# How to find out how many times a INTERVAL includes another one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, intervals

I have two `TIMESTAMP` and a `INTERVAL`. I want to know how many times the interval fits into the gap between the timestamps.

Subtracting two `TIMESTAMP` gives me an `INTERVAL`.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-30' -  TIMESTAMP '2019-01-29';

->
0 years 0 mons 1 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs
```

But I cant do a `INTERVAL / INTERVAL` division. This runs in an exception:

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2019-01-30' -  TIMESTAMP '2019-01-29') / INTERVAL '1 hour';
```

I would like to have an integer at the end. `24` for the previous example. Is there a way to handle it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize both intervals, e.g. by extracting the number of seconds and then dividing them:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from (TIMESTAMP '2019-01-30' -  TIMESTAMP '2019-01-29')) / extract(epoch from INTERVAL '1 hour');
```